# What exactly is happening when you set your provisioning profile to Automatic in XCode?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Trying to really get an understanding of code-signing and provisioning profiles. What provisioning profile is XCode using when you opt for Automatic? Your ad hoc profile?

Comment: This should be helpful (I don't remember if it answers your question directly, but it will save you a lot of time, I believe): https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/fastlane/docs/Codesigning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode creates a separate provisioning profile that it uses. It will not use a profile that was created manually.

If you add entitlements to your app, Xcode will also add those to the automatically managed provisioning profile.

Comment: So the provisioning profile created has nothing to do with any profiles configured by your developer account? What's the difference between an Ad Hoc profile created in the developer portal and this separate provisioning profile created when you opt for automatic?

Comment: The automatic profile is a development profile, not a distribution profile. So you cannot use it for Ad Hoc. Instead you should create an archive of your app and export it using a manually created profile.

Comment: @Mats, I believe, Xcode *can* use manually created profiles when in automatic mode. It's just that it might or might not use it. And it doesn't check if a matching certificate is installed.

Answer (score -1):

when you set provisioning profile is XCode Automatic you can not submit your ipa on app store.

you just  debug your app with xcode.

Comment: Actually, you can. It just depends on the profile that Xcode chooses (automatically). Sometimes it chooses a wildcard profile, and in this case, indeed, you can't submit an app.

Comment: I'm about 83.7% sure I'm not mistaken :)